# Spark Streaming Checkpoint not working after driver restart

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a simple spark streaming application which reads the data from the rabbitMQ
 and does some aggregation on window interval of  1 min and 1 hour for batch interval of 30s.

I have a three node setup. And to enable checkpoint,
 I have mounted the same directory using sshfs to all worker node for creating checkpoint.

When I run the spark streaming App for the first time it works fine .
 I could see the results being printed on console and some checkpoints happening in the network directory.

But After I kill the driver process and restarted , it fails with the following exception

```
        ERROR 2015-11-06 08:29:10 org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler: Error running job streaming job 1446778740000 ms.2
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 506.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 506.0 (TID 858, 10.29.23.166): java.lang.
Exception: Could not compute split, block input-0-1446778594400 not found
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.BlockRDD.compute(BlockRDD.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1273) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.4.1.3.jar:1.4.1.3]
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1264) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.4.1.3.jar:1.4.1.3]
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1263) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.4.1.3.jar:1.4.1.3]
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59) ~[scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47) ~[scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1263) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.4.1.3.jar:1.4.1.3]
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.4.1.3.jar:1.4.1.3]
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.4.1.3.jar:1.4.1.3]
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236) ~[scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:730) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.4.1.3.jar:1.4.1.3]
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1457) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.4.1.3.jar:1.4.1.3]
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1418) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.4.1.3.jar:1.4.1.3]
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48) [spark-core_2.10-1.4.1.3.jar:1.4.1.3]
WARN  2015-11-06 08:29:10 org.apache.spark.ui.jobs.JobProgressListener: Task start for unknown stage 507
WARN  2015-11-06 08:29:10 org.apache.spark.ui.jobs.JobProgressListener: Task start for unknown stage 508
WARN  2015-11-06 08:29:10 org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 509.0 (TID 882): java.lang.Exception: Could not compute split, block input-0-1446778
622600 not found
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.BlockRDD.compute(BlockRDD.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And the exception is repeated.

I am not pumping huge data to the rabbitMQ. When I run the job for the first time I am dumping only < 100 events . 
And when I run for the second time,  I have stopped the messages being sent to RabbitMQ from the producer process.

I have tried setting `"spark.streaming.unpersist","true"` .
And My Set up has 3 node each having one core allocated for spark and executor memory per node is 512MB.

Spark Version - 1.4.1 (DSE 4.8)

stratio receiver rabbitmq - [release 1.0](https://github.com/Stratio/RabbitMQ-Receiver)

code:

```
def createContext(checkpointDirectory: String, config: Config): StreamingContext = {
    println("Creating new context")

    val conf = new SparkConf(true).setAppName(appName).set("spark.streaming.unpersist","true")

    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(config.getInt(batchIntervalParam)))
    ssc.checkpoint(checkpointDirectory)
    val isValid = validate(ssc, config)

    if (isValid) {
      val result = runJob(ssc, config)
      println("result is " + result)
    } else {
      println(isValid.toString)
    }

    ssc
 }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    if (args.length < 1) {
      println("Must specify the path to config file ")
      println("Usage progname <path to config file> ")
      return
    }
    val url = args(0)
    logger.info("Starting " + appName)
    println("Got the path as %s".format(url))
    val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile(url)
    val lines = try source.mkString finally source.close()
    val config = ConfigFactory.parseString(lines)
    val directoryPath = config.getString(checkPointParam)

    val ssc = StreamingContext.getOrCreate(directoryPath, () => {
      createContext(directoryPath,config)
    })

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }


  def getRabbitMQStream(config: Config, ssc: StreamingContext): ReceiverInputDStream[String] = {
    val rabbitMQHost = config.getString(rabbitmqHostParam)
    val rabbitMQPort = config.getInt(rabbitmqPortParam)
    val rabbitMQQueue = config.getString(rabbitmqQueueNameParam)
    println("changing the memory lvel")
    val receiverStream: ReceiverInputDStream[String] = {
      RabbitMQUtils.createStreamFromAQueue(ssc, rabbitMQHost, rabbitMQPort, rabbitMQQueue,StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)
    }
    receiverStream.start()
    receiverStream
  }

  def getBaseDstream(config: Config, ssc: StreamingContext): ReceiverInputDStream[String] = {
    val baseDstream = config.getString(receiverTypeParam) match {
      case "rabbitmq" => getRabbitMQStream(config, ssc)
    }
    baseDstream
  }

  def runJob(ssc: StreamingContext, config: Config): Any = {

    val keyspace = config.getString(keyspaceParam)
    val clientStatsTable = config.getString(clientStatsTableParam)
    val hourlyStatsTable = config.getString(hourlyStatsTableParam)
    val batchInterval = config.getInt(batchIntervalParam)
    val windowInterval = config.getInt(windowIntervalParam)
    val hourlyInterval = config.getInt(hourlyParam)
    val limit = config.getInt(limitParam)

    val lines = getBaseDstream(config, ssc)
    val statsRDD = lines.filter(_.contains("client_stats")).map(_.split(",")(1))

    val parserFunc = getProtobufParserFunction()
    val clientUsageRDD: DStream[((String, String), Double)] = statsRDD.flatMap(x => parserFunc(x))
    val formatterFunc = getJsonFormatterFunc()
    val oneMinuteWindowResult = clientUsageRDD.reduceByKeyAndWindow((x: Double, y: Double) => x + y, Seconds(windowInterval), Seconds(batchInterval))
      .map(x => ((x._1._2), ArrayBuffer((x._1._1, x._2))))
      .reduceByKey((x, y) => (x ++ y))
      .mapValues(x => (x.toList.sortBy(x => -x._2).take(limit)))

    println("Client Usage from rabbitmq ")
    oneMinuteWindowResult.map(x => (x._1, DateTime.now, formatterFunc(x._2))).saveToCassandra(keyspace, clientStatsTable)
    oneMinuteWindowResult.print()

    val HourlyResult = clientUsageRDD.reduceByKeyAndWindow((x: Double, y: Double) => x + y, Seconds(hourlyInterval), Seconds(batchInterval))
      .map(x => ((x._1._2), ArrayBuffer((x._1._1, x._2))))
      .reduceByKey((x, y) => (x ++ y))
      .mapValues(x => (x.toList.sortBy(x => -x._2).take(limit)))

    HourlyResult.map(x => (x._1, DateTime.now, formatterFunc(x._2))).saveToCassandra(keyspace, hourlyStatsTable)
    HourlyResult.map(x => (x, "hourly")).print()

  }
}
```

Please help me in solving this issue.

Comment: Could you add the complete exception and the StreamingContext initialization code please?

Comment: Please find my main code here . I will post the exception.

Answer (score 3):

You are creating wrongly your StreamingContext to work with checkpointing.

As you can see here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/streaming-programming-guide.html#how-to-configure-checkpointing the correct way to instantiate a StreamingContext to use checkpointing is:

```
// Function to create and setup a new StreamingContext
def functionToCreateContext(): StreamingContext = {
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(...)   // new context
    val lines = ssc.socketTextStream(...) // create DStreams
    ...
    ssc.checkpoint(checkpointDirectory)   // set checkpoint directory
    ssc
}

// Get StreamingContext from checkpoint data or create a new one
val context = StreamingContext.getOrCreate(checkpointDirectory, functionToCreateContext _)

// Do additional setup on context that needs to be done,
// irrespective of whether it is being started or restarted
context. ...

// Start the context
context.start()
context.awaitTermination()
```

You only need to create a new StreamingContext instance if you don't have data in a specific checkpoint directory.

Also, regarding to the checkpointing folder, As far as I know, you need to install HDFS in your cluster instead of use sshfs to share the data between nodes:

> Configuring checkpointing - If the stream application requires it,
>   then a directory in the Hadoop API compatible fault-tolerant storage
>   (e.g. HDFS, S3, etc.) must be configured as the checkpoint directory
>   and the streaming application written in a way that checkpoint
>   information can be used for failure recovery

More info here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/streaming-programming-guide.html#requirements

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry I pasted the wrong code. Now I have edited and pasted the actual code.

Comment: This is the code that is causing the exception. And I am using NFS for checkpointing

Comment: After enabling the WAL , the code is working fine. But it has huge performance impact. The performance decreased by 50%.

Answer (score 0):

Two important points to be noted during restoring from checkpoint-

1. `spark.streaming.receiver.writeAheadLog.enable` should be `true` to enable write ahead log.
2. Creating `DStream`, iterating `RDD` batch, writing into HDFS and other stuffs should be done before returning `StreamingContext` inside the callback passed to `getOrCreate()`.

   ```
   def functionToCreateContext(): StreamingContext = {
       val ssc = new StreamingContext(...)   // new context
       val lines = ssc.socketTextStream(...) // create DStreams
       // do all stuffs here
       ssc.checkpoint(checkpointDirectory)   // set checkpoint directory
       // or here
       ssc
   }

   // Get StreamingContext from checkpoint data or create a new one
   val context = StreamingContext.getOrCreate(checkpointDirectory, functionToCreateContext _)

   // nothing can be done here once the context has been created by restoring from checkpoint

   // Start the context
   context.start()
   context.awaitTermination()
   ```

Here is the issue - ["SparkException: DStream has not been initialized" when restoring StreamingContext from checkpoint and the dstream is created afterwards](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13316)